# Why do std::optional constructors use std::in_place?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

Some [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) constructors use an [`std::in_place_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) tag parameter like this:

```
template< class... Args > 
explicit optional( std::in_place_t, Args&&... args );
```

I see that such constructors could be implemented without the in-place tag and use some `enable_if` (SFINAE) magic to not participate as unwilling overloads, i.e.:

```
template< class... Args > 
explicit optional( Args&&... args );
```

Why are `std::optional`’s in-place constructors implemented with an `std::in_place_t` tag rather than with some `enable_if` magic (and no tag)?

**Update:** Question is slightly updated to emphasize that I realize that simply omitting the in-place tag wouldn’t work.

Comment: That matches anything.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Why is that a problem?

Comment: Suppose `T` has an implicitly converting constructor taking  a single argument whose type does not equal `T`. Then you would create a temporary instead of using that value for in-place construction, without the chance of changing this.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl But you could SFINAE to prevent that. And actually, with or without a tag, a single argument is just forwarded. No temporaries created

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only case where the hypothetical tagless version fails is with default constructing the contained value

Comment: @PasserBy I now understood the forwarding in the single argument case. Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As Passer By said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767940/why-do-stdoptional-constructors-use-stdin-place/49768728#comment86551749_49767940), the intent is to disambiguate the situation where one wants to call the default constructor of `optional<T>` and the situation where one wants to call the default constructor of `T`.

This intention is proposed in [N3527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html#rationale.emplace), where the original proposed name of `in_place_t` is `emplace`. I quote the related part here:

> We need the extra tag to disambiguate certain situations, like calling `optional`'s default constructor and requesting `T`'s default construction:
>
> ```
> optional<Big> ob{emplace, "1"}; // calls Big{"1"} in place (no moving)
> optional<Big> oc{emplace};      // calls Big{} in place (no moving)
> optional<Big> od{};             // creates a disengaged optional
> ```

Comment: How do you search for papers/proposals?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I searched with the keywords "C++ in_place_t paper", and find N3793, then find N3527.

Comment: @0x499602D2 If you have access to the CppLang Slack, you can message npaperbot. It's really great!

Comment: @xskxzr If ```std::optional<T>``` constructor is fed in 2 args or more, can't it then be always assumed that these need to be forwarded to ```T's``` constructor and therefore not require ```in_place_t``` ?

Comment: @user3882729 It would be very odd that the interface for 2 or more args is different from the one for 1 arg.