# motivation behind in_place_t in std::optional constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

I'm trying to understand the motivation behind `in_place_t` in the `std::optional<T>` constructors a little better. I get the use case to disambiguate construction of `null` optional vs. type `T` with default constructor. However if there are one or more arguments specified to the `std::optional` constructor, can't it then be assumed that they can always be forwarded to construct `T` ?

```
#include <optional>

struct X
{
   X(int, int) {}
};

int main()
{
   std::optional<X> op{std::in_place, 1,2};
   //std::optional<X> op{1,2}; Does not compile, but why can't it be assumed that 1,2 always go to the constructor of X 
}
```

Comment: The duplicate answered a different question. This question is about the case where there are two or more parameters. Reopened.

Answer (score 3):

It comes down to another ambiguity. One example: if `T` can be constructed from `optional<T>`, what should happen when an `optional<T>` is constructed from an `optional<T>` object? Is the desired behavior copy construction of `optional<T>` or forwarding of the parameter to the `T` constructor?

This was addressed in [N3527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html#rationale.initialization_variants) (whose link I obtained from [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49768728).) The possibility of forwarding arguments was considered, but dismissed.

> However, there are also certain problems with this [perfect forwarding] model. First, there are exceptions to perfect forwarding: the tag `nullopt` is not forwarded. Also, arguments of type `optional<T>` are not. This becomes visible if T has such constructor:
>
> ```cpp
> struct MyType
> {
>   MyType(optional<MyType>, int = 0);
>   // ... 
> };
> ```
>
> Also, in general, it is impossible to perfect-forward initializer_list as the special deduction rules are involved.

The paper also identified a problem with default construction under perfect forwarding. (A default constructed `optional<T>` would contain a default-constructed `T` instead of not containing a value.) This part could be side-stepped – at the cost of some consistency – by requiring the `in_place_t` tag to construct an `optional<T>` that contains a default-constructed `T`. I view this as the lesser obstacle and the ambiguity issue as the major one.

---

I suppose you could press on and ask why not forward two or more arguments (when the first one is not the tag)? At some point consistency does become a desirable goal. Keep the interface simple. If a tag is needed for zero or one parameters to be forwarded to the constructor of `T`, then require it for any number of parameters. Fewer rules to remember results in fewer programming errors.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I just wanted to add that it's not _just_ about the ambiguity for `T` being constructible from `optional<T>` (although this is a good example), but it's actually _really tough_ for the developer implementing templates to have `Args...` forwarded from a _constructor_. Forwarding arguments are often unambiguously better matches than other constructors if they would otherwise have CV-differences of reference-collapsing occur. It's tough to write code that can forward an entire constructor to another one; `in_place_t` solves a whole lot of them.

Comment: @Human-Compiler could you please elaborate on what aspect is difficult w.r.t. forwarding Args... from a constructor vs. any other function?

Comment: @JaMiT W.r.t. ```If a tag is needed for zero or one parameters to be forwarded to the constructor of T, then require it for any number of parameters.``` interestingly enough a tag is not needed if there is exactly one argument.